# Export Data over network link in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, datapump

I want to take export of the `hr` schema in `test` database and import it to the `scott` schema in `Orcl` database over a network link by using data pump, in Oracle 10g.

User `system` (of `Orcl` database) has created a database link as:

```
create database link hrlink connect to hr identified by hr using 'remote_service';
```

By using this link system user can access schema of user `hr` without problem. These queries are working well and returning correct results:

```
conn system/sys
select * from tab@hrlink
select * from emp@hrlink
```

But when I try to export as follow from Linux:

```
$ expdp system/sys directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=hr.dmp schemas=hr network_link=hrlink
```

or:

```
$ impdp system/sys directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR remap_schema=hr:SCOTT network_link=hrlink
```

Both commands fail and raise errors like:

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
```

Comment: Wild guess: do you have multiple ORACLE_HOMEs on your local computer and are using the impdp/expdp from the wrong ORACLE_HOME?

Comment: Are you running the `expdp` and `impdp` from the `test` or `orcl` instance?

Comment: @'Alex Poole' looks right. You seem to be running expdp / impdp in 'test' database and not in 'orcl' DB where you actually created DB Link. Can you confirm @user1707821?